# Crossfire Setup not visible in Catalyst Center

Tags: windows-7, amd-catalyst, crossfire

I want to setup CrossfireX on my two HD 6870s but the CrossFire tab will not show up under neither "Gaming" nor "Performance. The Catalyst Center is the version that came along on the disk. See other specs below.

Thank you in advance.

---

Specs:
P8Z68-V PRO-GEN3, i5 2500K, 8 GB RAM, two Sapphire HD 6870s with CrossFireX bridge, 650W PSU, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that everything is hooked up. Are both your cards powered? Is the Crossfire bridge installed? Are the cards seated properly (try re-seating them anyway).

If none of that looks to be the issue, then *completely uninstall* the ATI drivers from your system (reboot if necessary), and then install them again. Sometimes if you installed the drivers with only one card installed, it will not recognize that you can enable Crossfire after you install the second card, even if it's hooked up properly.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out tomorrow. As this is a fresh build, there was not any drivers installed previous to the new cards.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that one of the four power cables was not properly connected.